# Extraction of values from line

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I need to extract key values in a line sequenctially.

For example I have a line : `"sometextp2nullp1key1p2val1p1key2p2val2"`. 
I need to obtain output as `"key1-val1,ke2-val2"`.

Can you please share some ideas ?

```
import re
with open ("url.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
```

Im stuck on moving forward from here...any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what are keys and values?

Comment: keys are  strings and they are  between  p1 and p2.. values are between p2 and p1 and for the end of the line value is between p2 and end of line. and keys need to start from p1... first p2 can be ignored.. i tried:                      
        print re.findall('p1(.*?)p2', line)
        print re.findall('p2(.*?)p1',line).. but im missing edge cases and it might break ..please advice a better way if possible...

Comment: So keys can be "p1" and "p2" and values can be "p1" and "p2"? And how are they separated? Please provide us with few inputs in order to see logic behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via regex:

```
print(re.findall(r'p1(.*?)p2(.*?)(?=p1|$)', line))
# [('key1', 'val1'), ('key2', 'val2')]
```

via splitting:

```
line = line.split('null')[-1]
print([tuple(item.split('p2')) for item in line.split('p1') if item])
# [('key1', 'val1'), ('key2', 'val2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear what keys and values are, you can solve problem using back references back-reference. If youu don't know what they are, you can read more about back-references [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

```
import re
with open ("url.txt", "r") as myfile:

    keys_values = []
    pattern = re.compile(r'(key\d)p\d(val\d)') 
    for line in myfile.readlines():

        for key_val in pattern.finditer(line):
           keys_values.append((key_val.group(1),key_val.group(2)))
```

This would give you list of `(key,val)` tupples. You can see  regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/U8Lxdy/1).

**Note:** 
Since it is not clear what keys and values are, you need to modify both back references in my regular expression in order to match your concrete input. Anyway, this code snipet should give you overall idea how this problem can be solved.